# 403 Response Code - Inputs correct?

Tags: java, url

Unsure how many of you are familiar with Bukkit / Mojang API, however, this is what I'm working with today. Though I don't believe this will suit any relevance to the problem as it seems to be a native issue.

I connect to the authentication service following Mojang's authentication wiki:
http://wiki.vg/Authentication#Authenticate

In my code, the 'MinecraftAccount' is just an object representing the payload in the above link, which I serialize with GSON.

I then want to grab the input response sent back, with properties you can also find in the link above. I use another object to hold the json values and deserialize it with Json (AuthResponse).

It seems I am doing everything right, but I get a 403 Error. I'm unsure why because after several attempts of getting this right, it worked, and then spontaneously began spitting out the 403 again. Hopefully you guys can see the issue here.

```
public String getAuthToken(MinecraftAccount minecraftAccount) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = Webs.getConnection("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");

        IOUtils.write(GsonProvider.standard().toJson(minecraftAccount), httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return GsonProvider.standard().fromJson(IOUtils.toString(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AuthResponse.class).getAccessToken();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

    public void uploadSkin(UUID uuid, String url, boolean normal) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new URL(url)), "png", baos);

        String authenticityToken = this.getAuthToken(this.minecraftAccount);

        try {
            System.out.println("Token: " + authenticityToken);

            if (authenticityToken == null) {
                return;
            }

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = Webs.getConnection(String.format(UPLOAD_SKIN_URL, UUIDTypeAdapter.fromUUID(uuid)));
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticityToken);
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
                writer.write("model=");
                if (!normal) {
                    writer.write("slim");
                }

                writer.write("&url=" + UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(url));
                System.out.println("status: " + httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage() + "(" + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + ")");
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Webs#getConnection is simply this (Using Proxy.NO_PROXY):

```
    public static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);

    httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    httpConnection.setReadTimeout(2 * TIMEOUT);

    httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
    return httpConnection;
}
```

PS: Yes, I have looked at several other 403 threads, however, their solutions (such as setting the user agent as a fix), doesn't work.

Ultimately, there's no error when calling #uploadSkin, it just returns a 403 and doesn't actually upload the file to the site or anything. The method just outputs this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxYpO.png)

Comment: Try using curl or postman to debug. Even when you get the 403 response, there should be an error message in the response.
Example: 
{
    "error": "ForbiddenOperationException",
    "errorMessage": "Invalid credentials. Invalid username or password."
}

Comment: No error returned. Just the 403 and "Forbidden" when calling httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage();

Comment: Like I said, try making the request using curl or postman. Also, check the getErrorStream() method.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to help pinpoint the issue. After reading what the error stream contains, I'm apparently specifying an invalid URL. I'm not sure how to get it 'hashed' like they do on the wiki: http%3A%2F%2Fassets.mojang.com%2FSkinTemplates%2Fsteve.png

Comment: Forgot to mention, it now returns a 500 error code, stating URL is invalid. I'm using the url in the wiki: http://assets.mojang.com/SkinTemplates/steve.png